# Scanning multiple integers from files into integer arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf

Tried looking for a question similar to mine, but didn't have much luck.

Working on the classic 'bin-packing problem' for my data structures class, but I'm getting hung up on a trivial matter: scanning integers.

This is the code for the troublesome function. Its purpose is to create three files:
    `bbsi.txt`
    `bbvi.txt`and
    `vbvi.txt`
This is handled by helper functions that I've already tested and that work. 'bbsi.txt' and 'bbvi.txt' have 50 integers each, whereas vbvi.txt has 100 integers. I pass four `int` arrays to read them in.

```
void intializeArrays(int BBSIitems[], int BBVIitems[], int VBVIbins[], int VBVIitems[])
{
    char *bbsiMaker = "bbsi.txt";
    char *bbviMaker = "bbvi.txt";
    char *vbviMaker = "vbvi.txt";

    FILE *makeBBSI = fopen(bbsiMaker, "w");
    FILE *makeBBVI = fopen(bbviMaker, "w");
    FILE *makeVBVI = fopen(vbviMaker, "w");

    srand(time(NULL));

    createBBSI(makeBBSI);
    createBBVI(makeBBVI);
    createVBVI(makeVBVI);

    int i;
    //puts all item sizes in the various arrays for use by the bin-packing heuristics
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        fscanf(makeBBSI, "%i", BBSIitems[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        fscanf(makeBBVI, "%i", BBVIitems[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        fscanf(makeVBVI, "%i", VBVIitems[i]);
    }

    //puts all bin sizes into the VBVIbins array for use by the VBVI heuristic
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        fscanf(makeVBVI, "%i", VBVIbins[i]);
        printf("%i\n", VBVIbins[i]);
    }

    //always gotta close those file streams..
    fclose(makeBBSI);
    fclose(makeBBVI);
    fclose(makeVBVI);

    return;
}
```

As an example, here is `vbvi.txt`.
(note: they are separated line by line in the text file.. not sure how to get that to happen on here)

`vbvi.txt`
   `41
    43
    89
    91
    64
    95
    70
    43
    42
    76
    74
    85
    63
    78
    62
    58
    91
    42
    92
    43
    71
    49
    61
    53
    79
    48
    57
    83
    72
    49
    80
    74
    54
    68
    66
    78
    65
    99
    84
    69
    74
    57
    55
    97
    96
    78
    57
    88
    80
    48
    53
    21
    105
    22
    79
    95
    86
    62
    21
    34
    38
    36
    28
    35
    71
    46
    72
    71
    43
    71
    85
    106
    71
    64
    25
    64
    33
    29
    102
    70
    72
    45
    34
    29
    101
    94
    104
    40
    45
    105
    54
    26
    30
    25
    41
    45
    105
    57
    96
    92`

To ensure the program was working properly, I had the program print out each value for the arrays. This is where the problem arises.

Output for `VBVIitems` and `VBVIbins`:
2090266759
0
1486921290
48
0
0
1556741664
32574
1
0
0
0
1
48
1489111448
48
-1021968384
6336833
0
0
0
0
1486944385
48
0
0
1489114336
48
1194362048
32767
0
0
1194362072
32767
0
1
0
0
1486882620
48
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1489111448
48
1486918310
48
19
0
1194362192
32767
1194362240
32767
1194362192
32767
1
0
1489114944
48
1910330751
0
1486918310
48
1489108688
48
1194362256
32767
63
48
1194362256
32767
3
0
1556740944
32574
-163754450
0
1486920631
48
1
32767
64550200
0
46
0
1491090000
48
0
0
1194362640
32767
1491090504
48

Looks an awful lot like addresses or something, but yeah.. Woof.

EDIT: Adding my array declarations and function call just in case there is something there worth noting.

```
int BBSIitems[50], BBVIitems[50], VBVIbins[50], VBVIitems[50];

intializeArrays(BBSIitems, BBVIitems, VBVIbins, VBVIitems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to open the file in `r` mode instead of `w` to read from it.
2. You have to change your `fscanf` statements to pass address of the variable to which the int has to be read.
   Like this-

   ```
   fscanf(makeBBSI, "%i", &BBSIitems[i]);
   //or
   fscanf(makeBBSI, "%i", BBSIitems + i);
   ```

Comment: Like I mentioned to Jud, I had tried that as well. I still get similar results.

Comment: I just edited the answer to add another bug i found. See if it helps

Comment: Aha! That was it. Just tested it, and it works perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in fscanf needs to be a pointer to the location in which to store the read value. Your code should be as follows (note the ampersand):

```
fscanf(makeBBSI, "%i", &BBSIitems[i]);
```

And so on for each fscanf call.

Comment: I had actually already tried that, but to no avail. I still get weird, address-like integers in my arrays.